# |Red Programming Language| How to get Cookies from a Webpage?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, rebol2, red

I searched a lot on Google as well as Stackoverflow. I could not find How to get Cookies (or in general, The HTTP Headers)from a Webpage and then edit it and send it back?

[I know how to make POST/GET requests using read/write but Cookies idk]

Comment: Red now has just temporary IO support that provides just basic functionality. For full IO support you should wait for 0.7.0.

Comment: Okay...  @rebolek 

BTW CTRL+F searching https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/runtime/simple-io.reds for `header` shows a lots of stuff. Are you sure it is not possible to extract the header yet?

Comment: This was just an assumption and @docKimbel proved me wrong, it’s possible even now, which is a good thing. Anyway, my point stands that full IO functionality is 0.7.0 thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even with the current temporary IO support, you can still extract HTTP headers and cookies info:

```
>> data: read/info http://microsoft.com
== [200 #(
Cache-Control: "no-cache, no-store"
Connection: "keep-alive"
Date: "Wed,...

>> list: data/2/set-cookie
== [{MS-CV=z/YnyU+5wE2gT8S1.1; domain=.microsoft.com; expires=Thu, 24-Mar-2016    10:59:39 GMT; pa...

>> foreach str list [probe parse str [collect [keep to "=" skip keep to [";" | end]]]]
["MS-CV" "z/YnyU+5wE2gT8S1.1"]
["MS-CV" "z/YnyU+5wE2gT8S1.2"]
```

The HTTP headers are stored in a map!, so if several `Set-Cookie` headers are sent, you will get a block of strings, else just a string for the `Set-Cookie` key.

`read/info` will return a block with 3 elements:

- HTTP return code (integer!)
- HTTP headers (map!)
- requested data (string! or binary!)

Notes:

- HTTPS is supported by `read` and `write`.
- the best place to get information about Red is to join the Red [chat room](https://gitter.im/red/red) on Gitter. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

cookies are just a field in the response header

did you try ["the library people"](http://www.rebol.org/search.r?find=cookie&form=yes)

Comment: rebol.org doesn't have any scripts for red-lang AFAIK